# mb_convert_encoding() throws error - unsupported character encoding UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I wanted to use TCPDF library for pdf generations. somehow tcpdf was not working for me. when i investigated into it, below line from tcpdf_fonts.php is culprit -

```
list(, $char) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($uch, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
```

mb_convert_encoding is throwing error unsupported character encoding UTF-8.

But when i am listing supported encode types using mb_list_encodings(), i can see UTF-8 as supported type. Still why i am getting this error?